# Compile Rescript with CLI -- no bsconfig.json

Tags: rescript

Is there a way to compile ReScript with just the CLI?

In other words, without the bsconfig.json?

Ideally, I would like to be able to just call the CLI and be able to compile into ES6, declare external dependencies, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The rescript compiler executable is called `bsc`, and I believe mroe or less takes the same options as [`ocamlc`](https://ocaml.org/manual/comp.html).

Assuming you have rescript installed locally, and two source files `main.res` and `foo.res` where `Main` depends on `Foo`, and with no other dependencies, you can compile them to commonjs modules by invoking the following commands:

```
npx bsc foo.res > foo.js
npx bsc -I . main.res > main.js
```

Unfortunately I don't think you can compile directly to es6 without `bsconfig.json`. The compiler option to do so is `-bs-package-output es6`, but that requires passing both `-bs-package-name` and a `bsconfig.json` file.

Comment: Hmm… followup then, is there a way to specify a bsconfig.json as a CLI argument for bsc?

Comment: I don't think so. I believe it will just look for it in the current working directory.